How to Remove Highlight Effect on Hover When Using Google Translate API
When I am using google translate in my website, text is getting highlighted on hover/mouseover. How to remove this highlight effects? This is my code
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    // get the desired translation language from the cookie
   
    var translateLang = getCookie('translate_lang');
    if (translateLang) {
        // set the cookie for the Google Translate API
        setCookie("googtrans", "/" + translateLang);
        // create the Google Translate widget
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            pageLanguage: "en",
            layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
        }, "google_translate_element");
    } else {
        console.log("Cookie is not set!!");
    }
}

I am excepting some thing similar to this, #goog-gt-tt { display: none !important; }, which was used to hide the google tool-tip on translated text. I am expecting similar code, to remove highlight on the translated text.

Unfortunately, you can't specify the ID or class directly because the class itself was generated by Google. But the workaround is that each text will be re-generated as a font component, so you can just change the CSS for the font component to this:
font {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

